# Help me rewrite the syntax in this statistics sentence

Tags: p-value

I'm editing a dissertation that has this sentence: "The regression analysis equation **demonstrates a F(1,44) = 6.220 and p = 0.016 was significant** on Problem 2 with the following question." I'm not well versed in statistics, but the syntax of the part in bold doesn't make sense to me. It appears this should be "demonstrates that." And it seems like the sentence should be written in plain English rather than containing two equations. Can anyone rewrite this sentence in plain English? Thank you very much.

Comment: I would have gone with something like _the value of the $F$ statistic is ---- and the corresponding $p$ value is ----_.

Comment: Not that you have to accept my answer, but nitpicking the language as an aside, it's an annoying habit even among seasoned scientists to conflate the "demonstration" aspect of testing in regards to showing an association vs. achieving a very specific result. In a sense F=6.220 doesn't demonstrate anything, but it is highly inconsistent with the range of values expected when there's no association. I have even read papers where scientists claimed that a result of p=0.053 is statistically significant at the 0.053 level!!!

Comment: Having read many theses in obscure quasi-scientific disciplines that employ statistical procedure, I have grown to believe that the principal value of abuses of language like that is to alert the reader that the writer (as well as any previous reviewers, including and not limited to their thesis advisor and committee) likely does not understand the statistical procedure(s) they are using, and therefore warns us to view all results with healthy scepticism.

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition seems to be right, since, though I understand what you mean, there are a few mistakes. Mainly, you're missing the hypothesis, or at least it's not stated explicitly. I'm assuming it is stated elsewhere, like in the methods section, but when stating results it's helpful to rerefer to previously established language. As an old advisor said of scientific writing/presenting: "tell them what you'll tell them, tell them, then tell them what you told them."

Since this is a one (numerator) degree of freedom test, you seem to be testing for significance of a particular cofactor or variable, what we'd usually call the "X". You can strengthen the argument by specifically referring to the significance test of "X". So rather than refer to the "regression analysis equation" (which is vague and a noun-stack), you could say, "**The significance test for X had an F-statistic of 6.220 and a p-value of 0.016**". In the next sentence, you can go farther say, "And so we reject the hypothesis that "X" is unassociated with "Y"" if you have a pre-stated alpha level for this analysis which happens to be 0.016... such as, say, 0.049.

It's typically not necessary to state the numerator, denominator degrees of freedom, in fact you can omit the F value altogether.